# Is there a way to find out which USB interface Mac OS has a driver attached to?

Tags: macos, usb, iokit

I'm trying to debug a libusb function called libusb_kernel_driver_active(). It tells if a USB device has an operating system driver attached to it. It takes an interface number as one of its arguments. I want to be able to find out which interface the operating system's driver is currently attached to. Is there a way to do this using a terminal command or IOKit?

I have tried IORegistryExplorer but it doesn't list this information.
ioreg does not appear to list USB interface information.

Maybe someone out there knows of an IOKit function that can tell us the information we want.

Comment: I would say it is the thing you can do with IORegistryExplorer. For example: my usb web-camera exports audio device. 
It is controlled by com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio driver (which I can see with sudo kextstat) and there is a record in IORegistryExplorer, where the parent of the AppleUSBAudioDevice (which CFBundleId is com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio) is IOUSBHostInterface@2. 
Is your question about how to automate this search conviniently?

Comment: @ArthurBulakaiev Thank you very much for this information. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

To find this information out, open the IORegistryExplorer program (spotlight can find it). Then select IOService from the drop down menu in the upper left corner of the window. In the search bar type the name of your device. If it is found select in on the tree below. Then delete all text from the search field to see all the available fields.

[image]

Comment: Note that `IORegistryExplorer` is part of the "Additional Tools For Xcode" package, which must be downloaded from the ["More Downloads" page](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/) on Apple's developer web site. (Login with Apple ID required.)

Answer (score 2):

The IORegistryExplorer answer is correct, but as the question hints at, there are other ways to obtain the information, both on the Terminal and programmatically.

### Terminal (`ioreg`)

The command

```
ioreg -irc IOUSBDevice
```

Will list all USB devices detected by the system, as well as any client objects in the I/O Registry. This means either the driver client directly (kext, dext, or user space) or the `IOUSBInterface` objects representing the different interfaces on a composite device, and the driver clients attached to each of those.

You can search by name instead of class type by using the `-n` option instead of `-c` but often the USB-level name doesn't match the retail name of the device, or is somehow abbreviated. It's usually easier to inspect *all* USB devices manually.

### Programmatically

In your program, you can search for all USB devices in the system using something like this:

```
    io_iterator_t device_iter = IO_OBJECT_NULL;
    IOReturn ret = IOServiceGetMatchingServices(kIOMasterPortDefault, IOServiceMatching(kIOUSBDeviceClassName), &device_iter);

    if (ret == kIOReturnSuccess && device_iter != IO_OBJECT_NULL)
    {
        while (io_service_t device = IOIteratorNext(device_iter))
        {
            io_name_t device_name = "";
            IORegistryEntryGetName(device, device_name);
            // do something with device_name…
        }
    }
```

Once you have selected your device, you can then use [`IORegistryEntryCreateIterator()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iokit/1514318-ioregistryentrycreateiterator?language=objc) to iterate over its child objects (possibly recursively), which should allow you to identify the driver being used or obtain any other information you require.

Comment: Parsing the output of "ioreg -irc IOUSBDevice" does sound easy to do. Thank you for that answer.

I do have a request. Could you show us a full program that display's an USB device's interface and attached driver?